# find submatrixes in matrixes

Tags: c, matrix

I'm trying to find sub-matrices in matrices. matrices are square 2-D matrices of integer (NxN). I need to find a sub matrix of integers with same values in same order in the big matrix. like a crop of pixels from the big matrix. the square matrices and the square sub matrices are read by file.

The initialization of the matrices works fine. I just couldn't find what the problem with the `find`, `matching`, `distance` functions.

The problem is I don't find any matches except for one matrix.

Do you have any idea what might be the problem?

```
typedef struct
{
    int size;
    int *data;
} Matrix;

int distance(int p, int o)
{
    //printf("p %d o %d 0:%f 1: %f 2:%d\n", p, o, (double)(p - o) / p, ceil((double)(p - o) / p), abs(ceil((double)(p - o) / p)));
    return abs(ceil((double)(p - o) / p));
}

int matching(Matrix pic, int y, int x, Matrix obj, float value)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int colStart = x;
    for (int i = 0; i < obj.size; i++, y++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < obj.size; j++, x++)
        {
            sum += distance(pic.data[(y) * pic.size + (x)], obj.data[i * obj.size + j]);
            if (sum > value)
                return 0;
        }

        x = colStart;
    }
    return sum < value;
}

int *find(Matrix p, Matrix *matOfObjects, int size, int (*pos)[3][2], float value)
{
    int count = 0;
    int *matchObjs = (int *)malloc(3 * sizeof(int));

    if (matchObjs == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: failed to allocate memory for array\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= p.size - matOfObjects[k].size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= p.size - matOfObjects[k].size; j++)
            {
                if (count > 2)
                    return matchObjs;
                else if (j + matOfObjects[k].size > p.size || i + matOfObjects[k].size > p.size) // out of bound of picture check
                    continue;
                else if (matching(p, i, j, matOfObjects[k], value))
                {
                    matchObjs[count] = k + 1;
                    (*pos)[count][0] = i;
                    (*pos)[count][1] = j;
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (count > 2)
        return matchObjs;
    else
    {
        free(matchObjs);
        return NULL;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int size, numOfps, numOfobjs;
    float matchingV;
    FILE *fp = fopen(FILENAME, "r"); // Open file for reading
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: failed to open file '%s'\n", FILENAME);
        exit(1);
    }
    fscanf(fp, "%f %d", &matchingV, &numOfps);

    Matrix *arrP = readMatrixes(&fp, numOfps);
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &numOfobjs);
    Matrix *arrO = readMatrixes(&fp, numOfobjs);
    fclose(fp); // Close file

    int foundObjs[3];
    int positions[3][2];

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfps; i++)
    {
        int *arr = find(arrP[i], arrO, numOfobjs, &positions, matchingV);
        if (arr != NULL)
        {
            memcpy(foundObjs, find(arrP[i], arrO, numOfobjs, &positions, 0.100000), 3 * sizeof(int));
            if (!foundObjs)
            {
                printf("Error: failed to copy array\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            printf("Picture %d: found Objects:", i + 1);
            for (int j; j < 3; j++)
                printf(" %d Position(%d,%d)", foundObjs[j], positions[j][0], positions[j][1]);
            printf("\n\n");
        }
        else
            printf("Picture %d: No three different Objects were found\n", (i + 1));
        free(arr);
    }
    // write_matrix_to_file("output.txt", numOfobjs, arrO);
    freeMatrix(arrP, numOfps);   // Free memory
    freeMatrix(arrO, numOfobjs); // Free memory

    /*testing------------------------------------------------
     Matrix mat;
     Matrix sub;
     int m[9] = { 1,
                  2,
                  3,
                  4,
                  5,
                  6,
                  7,
                  8,
                  9 };
     int m2[4] = { 2,    return count > 2 ? matchObjs : NULL;
     {
         for (int j = 0; j <= mat.size - sub.size; j++)
         {
             printf("check %d\n", j);
             if (matching(mat, i, j, sub, 0.100000))
                 printf("%d %d true\n", i, j);
             else
                 puts("false");
         }
     }
     for (int i = 0; i < sub.size; i++)
         for (int j = 0; j < sub.size; j++)
             printf("%d\n", sub.data[i * sub.size + j]);
             */
    return 0;
}
```

I tried testing with fewer values and it worked. i expect to find few matches.

the output is:

```
Picture 1: No three different Objects were found
Picture 2: No three different Objects were found
Picture 3: No three different Objects were found
Picture 4: No three different Objects were found
Picture 5: found Objects: 1 Position(20,20) 1 Position(300,300) 5 Position(200,200)
```

Comment: You should explain what the problem is.

Comment: `for (int j; j < 3; j++)` is obviously going to not behave...

Comment: @Fe2O3 
 i noticed that. but still getting same results

Comment: @AllanWind  i noticed that sorry

Comment: To me this question is very unclear. What do you mean by "find sub-matrices in matrices". What is the criteria?

Comment: @SupportUkraine matrices are matrices of integer. I need to find a sub matrix of integers with same values in same order in the big matrix. like a crop of pixels from the big matrix.

Comment: @IdoS99 What does the struct `Matrix` represent? A single row of a 2-D matrix with size `size`? A 2-D matrix with `size` elements (then how do you know the columns/rows?)? A square 2-D matrix?